# Find number of non duplicate items in 2 different arrays with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to find the number of items in two arrays which are not duplicate.

Eg here the answer is 1:

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
const array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Eg here the answer is 2:

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b']
const array2 = ['a', 'x', 'y']
```

My solution works for some inputs but not all:

```
function something(a, b) {

    let aArray = a.split("");
    console.log(aArray);
    let bArray = b.split("");
    console.log(bArray);

    aArray.forEach((aItem, aIndex)=> {
        console.log(aItem)
        bArray.forEach((bItem, bIndex)=> {
            console.log(bItem);
            if(aItem === bItem) {
                console.log(aIndex, bIndex);
                aArray[aIndex] = "-";
                bArray[bIndex] = "-";
            }
        });

    });

    console.log(aArray);
    console.log(bArray);

    const aRes = aArray.filter(item=> item !== "-").length;
    console.log(aRes)

    const bRes = bArray.filter(item=> item !== "-").length;
    console.log(bRes)

    const res = aRes + bRes;
    console.log(res)

     return res;
}
```

Comment: _I need to find the number of items in two arrays which are not duplicate._ doesn't it should be 3 `x,y,b` in the second example ??

Comment: Are you able to use `jQuery` @Evans ?

Answer (score -1):

Stealing from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034768/4903754

```
let difference = arr1
             .filter(x => !arr2.includes(x))
             .concat(arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x)));
```

Comment: Wouldn’t that return an empty array for the first example where the answer should be `1`?